# Streaming download the file on S3 with ActionController::Live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am now creating the web service that needs broadcasting video from S3 and show it with html5 video.

As a business logic, it must not allow a direct access, because I don't want users to know from where the video data come and access it. It means that I don't want to use `redirect_to`.To achieve this, I thought what if Rails intercepts streaming of the video data using any streaming logics with `206 partial content`. To sum up, imitating a direct access of S3.

However, I actually have not done this kind of stuff, so **I would like to know some useful, informative sources or techniques you guys have tried or know.**

Currently, I am trying implementation something like below, but still feeling my way around. Need some advice.

```
class VideoController < ApplicationController
  include ActionContoller::Live

  ...

  def source
    s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
    s3.get_object(bucket "mybucket", key: "myvideo") do |chunk|
      response.stream.write chunk
      sleep 1
    end
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end

  ...
end
```